Possible noise from tps63020(buck converter) that is affecting audio MAX98357
I'm pretty new to the engineering but I hope this will be an easy question for those who have done much job in this area.
So I'm making my own pcb that consists mainly of esp32-s3, 2x tps63020 (3.3 and 5 volts) and max98357(i2s audio amp).
Currently everything is working perfectly as I expected except one thing. Audio on the almost max volume is not that clear as I believed. It is actually playing quite well, but on bass parts gives in my subjective opinion has high frequency noise that might go from buck converter.
Here I applied my schematics:

I added the whole schematics of my board but the interesting part is in the red square.
Here is my pcb top layer:

Here is my pcb bottom layer:

I currently don't have oscilloscope to measure if there is actual noise or no, but what I can definitely say, that if I power max98357 directly from usb port of my pc audio becomes clear.
PS. I could record the sound and then you might get wider view on the problem, or it might be just as simple as I need to have a couple of additional capacitors on that power lane.
